# JsonResult not printing objected returned

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to send a json response in my Controller, but it's not sending everything that i pass as a argument. I'm getting the objects from EF and i store it in a var and return Json(cardsList).

The method that gets the data from EF.

```
public Task<List<Card>> AllCardsAsync()
```

My controller method declaration is:

```
[HttpGet("cards")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Get()
    {
        var cards = await _unitOfWork.CardRepository.AllCardsAsync();
        return Json(cards);
    }
```

The Card.cs definition is

```
 public partial class Card
{
    public Card()
    {
        Archive = new HashSet<Archive>();
        Owns = new HashSet<Owns>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Representation { get; set; }
    public int ActionId { get; set; }
    public int CoordinatorId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Archive> Archive { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Owns> Owns { get; set; }
    public virtual Action Action { get; set; }
    public virtual Coordinator Coordinator { get; set; }

  }
```

When i debbug, cardsList has 3 elements and alot more infomation, but the result i get in the browser is and array with only 1 element and alot less information.

Thanks in advance
[UPDATE]
Action.cs and Coordinator.cs

```
public partial class Action
{
    public Action()
    {
        Call = new HashSet<Call>();
        Card = new HashSet<Card>();
        SendCoordinates = new HashSet<SendCoordinates>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ActionTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Call> Call { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Card> Card { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SendCoordinates> SendCoordinates { get; set; }
    public virtual ActionType ActionType { get; set; }
}


 public partial class Coordinator
{
    public Coordinator()
    {
        Card = new HashSet<Card>();
        Owns = new HashSet<Owns>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Card> Card { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Owns> Owns { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: Can you share the code you use on the front end to display the data?

Comment: I still don't use it in front-end. I just send the response by returning Json(cards) in the handler.

Comment: I suspect that it does not know how to serialize generic lists such as ICollection, you would have to use a more concrete List of T instead. If it isn't serializing Action or Coordinator, would need to see those classes to understand why it isn't serializing those.

Comment: instead of using var cards? have it as a List<Card> ? this doesn't work, same result. i'll update with those classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have Lazy Loading disabled for EF, your collection properties are going to be null (by default), so when you serialize them they're not going to show up. You need to manually .Include() them when you fetch your result and disable lazy loading so that they're eager loaded.

A better approach is to define your own ViewModel type - you typically don't want to expose your data model types as your API model. Then you can populate it however you want and flatten it our or otherwise restructure it to optimize it for HTTP clients as opposed to database clients. You might create your own custom ViewModel type and populate it manually (just instantiate it and set its properties) and see if you get that serialized correctly. Then map from EF to the ViewModel using LINQ projection (e.g. `.Select()`) or a tool like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

Comment: I include them; var all = _context.Card.Include(c => c.Coordinator)
                                        .Include(c => c.Owns)
                                        .Include(c => c.Action)
                                        .ThenInclude(a => a.ActionType);

Comment: good ideia, thank you, but why would creating a viewModel make it serialize well?

Comment: You could ensure it was structured appropriately and flattened and also be certain you were working with that type and not a dynamic proxy (as EF would use with lazy loading). You could ensure for instance no circular properties where A has property B that has property A which tend to cause serialization problems. Basically you have more control.

Comment: By flattened you mean, have a CardViewModel.cs with lets say some properties of the Coordinator, like username, password, instead of having one Coordinator property?

Comment: Yes, exactly that kind of thing.